# Getting input values without rerender

Tags: reactjs

I have a text input (for the search text) and a button (to initiate the search). It seems from all the examples, that in order to have the searchtext value available in my search click handler (to trigger an Action), I have to have the input use a state value and update the state when the onChange occurs. This causes rerendering. How can I avoid all the rerenders when the user is just typing chars into the input? I only want the value at the time the search button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: implement `shouldComponentUpdate` for your component: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

EDIT:

- **Don't** link `this.state` to your input element's value (`<input value={this.state} />`), this makes the input an uncontrolled component
- Instead just give it a `ref`: `<input ref={input => {this.inputElement = input}} />`
- When the submit button is hit just get the input value via the ref:

  `const inputValue = this.inputElement.value`

Comment: Then the searchtext input does not update. Because I have the searchtext input value set to this.state.searchText and the onChange calls setState setting searchText to e.target.value.

Comment: Well of course you will get re-renders if you have `this.state` in your render function. That's the whole point of it. Check out this section of the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: I think I got it. Make the input an uncontrolled component with a ref. Use reactDOM to get its value when the search button is pressed.

Comment: updated my answer to give a better overview for necessary steps. Glad you got it working :)

Comment: We can also use PureComponent instead of Component if we don't want to manually handle shouldComponentUpdate life cycle method for the component.
When props or state changes, PureComponent will do a shallow comparison on both props and state. Component on the other hand won't compare current props and state to next out of the box.