# React - Result List rerenders if search text is entered

Tags: reactjs

I'm still unexperienced with react so that even after searching for a solution and finding some pointers I still cant grasp what the problem is or how to solve it.

I have a Component that renders a list of images. It also contains a search input. I copy the search input onChanged to the state. If onKeyPressed is the return key or when the search button is pressed, that text is again copied from state to the state.searchTerm. The search itself is an effect that watches for changes in searchTerm an then executes a search, updating the list of images. However I feel like, because I change the state with every onChange in the search input, I trigger a re-render of the entire component including the list of images which is just annoying. How can I get rid of this?

I tried to shrink my styled and dynamic code to a minimal working version. What would be the best way to solve this? Would it help to split list and search into separate components with individual state with the parent just holding the list of assets, passing it to the list child and the search child getting a reference to onSearch?
But then I just move the problem since if the search child re-renders, the parent will as well, right?

```
function AssetListTool ({}) {

  const [assets, setAssets] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  const params = {
    limit: 30,
    sort: 'title:desc',
    searchTerm
  };

  const Asset = memo(function ({asset }) {
    return <>
      <div className="asset">
          <img src={asset.thumbnail} />
      </div>
    </>;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const matchingAssets = assetApi.getAllAssets({...params });
    Promise.all([matchingAssets],
    ).then(responses => {
      setAssets(assets.concat(responses[0].items));
    });
  }, [searchTerm]);

  const onSearchTextChanged = useCallback((event) => {
    setSearchText(event.target.value);
  }, [searchText]);

  function onSearchKeyPressed(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      onSearch();
    }
  }

  function onSearch() {
    setAssets([]);
    setSearchTerm(searchText);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>
          <input onChange={onSearchTextChanged} onKeyPress={onSearchKeyPressed} value={searchText}
                 type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={onSearch}>
            <Icon icon={faSearch}/>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

     <div>
        {assets && assets.length > 0 &&
          <div>
            {assets.map((asset) => <Asset asset={asset}/>)}
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


export default AssetListTool;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, should've searched just a little more and I was on the right track... The solution is to not touch the state for the text input and instead use a reference to it which is then read for the search as was explained here:

[Getting input values without rerender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254808/getting-input-values-without-rerender?rq=1)

Thought about a local variable but that didnt work and using event.target.value was always missing the last input. So ref is the trick here..